# AngularJs- popup loading time issue

Tags: angularjs

Am using angularJs. For opening popup am using  createDialogService.
    createDialogService('myPopUp.html',
    {
    });
    If am using like this means popup is getting loaded after long time.  Am facing performance issue.
    I need to show fraction of seconds.
    Any one knows please update me. Thank in advance

Comment: Have you looked at bootstrap modal?

Comment: yes. Is there any param to specify time in this createDialogService

Comment: You need to post `createDialogService` source.